# How to read ROS2 bag file in ROS1?

Tags: ros, ros2, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I would like to convert a ROS2 bag file (.db3) to ROS1 bag file (.bag). [This question](https://answers.ros.org/question/352466/converting-ros2-bag-to-ros1-bag/) has been asked before but we no answer so I decided to repeat it by adding another question as well.

also, is it possible to read the ROS2 bag file within ROS1? I have found a [plugin](https://github.com/ros2/rosbag2_bag_v2) which does the inverse but I did not find anything related to what I need.

Any idea?
Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/388484/how-to-read-ros2-bag-file-in-ros1?/) by [Mobile_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/11921/mobile_robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 264 on 2021-10-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-10-12**:
You already found #q352466 yourself. Please don't post duplicates.

**Comment by [Mobile_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/11921/mobile_robot/) on 2021-10-12**:
I am sorry, but as an admin you should be more careful. This is NOT the same question. Please read carefully the Titles. This is the question on how READING the robag2 file within ROS1. But inside of this question, the previous question on how to CONVERT the ROS2 bag file to ROS1 bag file has been mentioned!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-10-12**:
I'm not sure I understand your comment (and the caps are not needed).

I'm also not sure whether the distinction between reading and converting is sufficient to warrant a new question.

Part of conversion is reading.

If you really want a separate answer, I'll re-open and post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> is it possible to read the ROS2 bag file within ROS1?

no, this is not supported right now. `rosbag` in ROS 1 does not have the same "pluggable storage backend" concept as `rosbag` in ROS 2 has. That plugin system is what makes the plugin you found work.

Unless someone extends `rosbag` with this capability of course.

To do that, you could use the Python library mentioned in #q352466 (although the core of `rosbag` is actually C++), but I doubt it would be trivial to make such a process robust, as the mapping between ROS1<->ROS2 topics is not always obvious (or even feasible).

Extending `rosbag` is possible though. See [ros/ros_comm#1206](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/1206) and [ros/ros_comm#1499](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/1499) which added bag encryption to `rosbag`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0